# Hiding DefaultProperty

Tags: java, javafx

Is there any way to hide DefaultProperty?

Let's say I have such class:

```
public class CustomNode extends HBox {

    //Things

}
```

As we know, default property for HBox is *children*, so default property for my CustomNode is also *children*.

Is there any way to hide/remove the default property without creating a new one? (I'd like to extend, so other ways are not okay for me)

I want to do this, because I don't want to have chance to make a mistake in FXML coding.

Answer (score 0):

No. You cannot do that with inheritance. When you extends the HBox class (or any class) you really say that your CustomNode `is-a` HBox, that is the relationship.

Maybe you can introduce you own `interface` is that makes more sense to you.